# Permanent category order

Tags: magento-1.9, category, magmi

How can I make the order of magento categories permanent so it doesn't change every time I import with magmi?

I was thinking of reassigning each category with the position value but I can't seem to find it.

Another way might be to write a script that moves the first category to the desired category to put it first and so on until it's done, but how do I move categories in a script?

Is there a way to fix this with magmi?

Comment: I must be mistaken but as far as i remember, MAGMI does not shuffle the categories on import. When using `On the fly category creator/importer` it would just add any new categories to the end of the relevant branch. May you post some lines of your CSV and also explain, what the category structure should look like?